# How do I create a Folder called "My Folder" in Android when the User presses a Button?

Tags: java, android

I want the App to Create a Folder in the SD card, when the user presses the button.

I added the Manifest Code:

Here is My Java Code:

public void onClick(View v) {

```
                File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Naya");
                if (!path.exists()) {
                    path.mkdir();
                        // do something                        
                }
            }
```

No Folder gets Created and it shows "mkdir() is ignored".
Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android java : How to create folder inside android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320346/android-java-how-to-create-folder-inside-android-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954293/permission-to-read-data-from-sd-card) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card)

Comment: Tried, The Method is Deprecated now, So I had to lower my API version as I don't know about the new Methods